# mAP using Tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

After I train my object detector using the Tensorflow object detection API(to detect only cars).

I get an mAP value around 0.32 while running the eval.py script.

However, in the Tensorflow Detection model Zoo page(which can be accessed at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md), the mAP's for various models are 100 times the value I have obtained but when I look at my model's predictions on the test set, they are actually pretty good.

Should I multiply the value which I have obtained by 100 or is there something wrong with the model that I have trained?

Comment: the raw mAP you get from your algorithm will be between [0,1] and when expressed in % will be [0,100]

Comment: So I can express my mAP while reporting as 32 right?

Comment: Yes. simply multiply by 100 to obtain mAP in percent from the raw metric, meaning 32 in your case.